# Appending component inside the div using class name as reference

Tags: angular, angular-components

It is possible to append the component in to the view using the ViewContainerRef.

For Example,
HTML File:

```html
<div #Ref>it is possible to append the component here</div>
```

TS File:

```typescript
@ViewChild("Ref", { read: ViewContainerRef })
public Ref: ViewContainerRef

appendComponent() {
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
    SingleframeComponent
  );
  this.Ref.createComponent(factory);
}
```

But in my case I want to append the component dynamically using the class and its index ref
For Example

HTML File

```html
<div #Ref>
  <div class="appendComponentHere"></div>
  <div class="appendComponentHere"> I need to append The component Here</div>
  <div class="appendComponentHere"></div>
</div>
```

TS File

```typescript
@ViewChild("Ref", { read: ViewContainerRef })
public Ref: ViewContainerRef

appendComponent() {
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.

  //something like this i need to do

  this.Ref.element .nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("fullslidebody")[1].createComponent(factory);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy. Just try the following:

```typescript
const viewRef  = this.Ref.createComponent(factory).hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

const target = this.Ref.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("fullslidebody")[1];
target.appendChild(viewRef.rootNodes[0]);
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efnqu3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**